# How can a seg fault in NASM cause failure of code execution before the offending lines?

Tags: assembly, x86, segmentation-fault, printf, nasm

I am writing a subroutine to be called in NASM, without posting all of my code for this, let me just tell you that I'm sure there are issues with it, like stack imbalance.

Just before this subroutine is called, the user is asked for a number that is stored in variable "factInt". The value of this is then output to the screen before the routine call.

If the program is as follows:

```
;print value
push dword [factInt]
push formati
call printf
add esp, 8

;debug
ret

;call factorial
push dword [factInt]
call fact
```

Then the output is the input integer, eg:

```
6
```

However, if we remove the debug line (ret), the program asks for an integer, and seg faults before the print out. How is it possible, since the program needs to print out before it even gets to any issue with stack imbalance in the subroutine?

This is contrary to what ive learned in years of programming in other languages such as java!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to remember that output through `printf` is *buffered*. If the program crashes before the buffer has been flushed the output in the buffer is lost.

It can easily be solved by adding a newline to the output format string, as the output is line buffered (i.e. the buffer is flushed on newline).

Comment: this does seem to be correct.... my format was (formati: db "%i", 0).... and if i change this to (formati: db "%i", 10, 0).... i actually get output from the print before the sub, AND from within the sub before the segfault is thrown!

Comment: So, if i keep calling printf over and over passing new stuff to it, it will not under any circumstance put this info to the screen until it reaches a printf statement that includes the "10" character?

Comment: @Drifter64 It will of course flush the buffer (write to terminal) when it's full. But adding a newline is the simplest solution.